# Help for proving rank of matrix

Tags: matrix-rank

[image]

This is a problem from our practice exam. Could anyone tell me how to approach this question and prove details.

Super appreciate!

Comment: The general idea for homework sort of stuff is that you make some effort, or at least outline where you are having difficulty. Also, the scan is a little hard to read mainly because of all the white space.

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked 4 questions in your first 2 days on the site. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Answer (score 0):

a) An injective linear map always will preserve the dimension of the domain space, because  it maps linearly independent set to linearly independent set.
Therefore dim(im(T))=dim(domain space)=n where $m>n$.

b)Rank and Nullity theorem is a classical theorem in Linear algebra. dim(ker)+dim(im)=dim(domain space). T is onto, so dim(im)=m. From this you can deduce that dim(ker)=n-m where $n>m$

c) From $(a)$ and $(b)$ you can answer yourself the third question